# Dealing a 5 card hand with exactly 1 pair

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

Here's the question:

> A 5-card hand is selected from a standard deck of playing cares. (A standard deck has 13 cards from each of
>   4 suits{clubs, diamonds, hearts, and spades. The 13 cards have face value 2 through 10, jack, queen, king,
>   or ace. Each face value is \kind" of card. The jack, queen, and king are \face cards.") How many hands contain exactly one pair?

And here's the provided answer:

> We can view this as a sequence of events. First, select the face value for the pair. There are 13 choices
>   for this. Next, select which two cards of that face value will make up the pair. Thus, we want to select
>   2 cards from the 4 of that face value at this step. There are C(4; 2) = 6 ways to do this. Third, we need
>   to select the other three cards. These other three cards cannot contain any pairs. There are 48 ways
>   to select the rest of these cards, since we have to exclude the cards with the face value of the pair. The
>   next card has 44 options, since we cannot select any of the two face values used thus far. The third of
>   these three cards has 40 options, since we cannot use any of the 3 face values already used. However,
>   we are over counting by all possible ways to arrange these three cards, so we must divide out by the
>   number of arrangements, namely 3! = 6. The final answer is:
>   (13*6*48*44*40)/6
>   = 1098240

I understand all of the steps except one: how are we over counting? P(3,3) = 6 which implies that the ordering of the cards in the hand matters, which makes no sense to me because it's still the same hand regardless of what order it's in. So how are we over counting, where is 3!=6 coming from if not P(3,3).

Thanks!

OSFTW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order does not matter, as you say. However, we counted the last three cards as if order does matter. We correct for this by dividing by $3!$.

Comment: So, by selecting one card, then the next card, then the next card (as opposed to say all 3 at once which isn't possible since we need to make sure no two are the same kind), we counted as if order mattered?? I think that makes sense, so we'll have to account for that by dividing by 3!. Could you go into a bit more explanation about how we count the 3 cards as if order mattered? 

Thanks!

Comment: We counted Kh, Qs, Jd and we also counted Jd, Kh, Qs and also four other permutations. But these are really all the same. Similarly for every other triple; we counted each one six times.

Comment: Kh, Qs, Jd?? What do you mean by those?

Comment: King of hearts, Queen of spades, Jack of diamonds.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks! Answer selected.

Comment: My understanding of things: Because we did C(48,1), C(44,1) and C(40,1) we counted the deck 3 times over (for every kind we didn't pull out), which is why we're correcting it?

Comment: Not quite. An example of something that we want to count once is the hand {2h, 2d, Kh, Qs, Jd}. It is a set, so order doesn't matter. The hand {2h, 2d, Qs, Kh, Jd} is the same hand, and should not be counted again. But we did count it again. In fact, we counted it 6 times, because there are six orders in which we can choose the last three cards. So we have to divide by 6.

Comment: Numerically, where is the over counting occurring? I'm looking at the solution, minus the division by 6, and I still don't see where we're over counting. I appreciate your patience, something just isn't clicking.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not know how else to explain it. Try it with a smaller deck of cards, maybe?

Comment: Ok no problem! Thanks a lot for all of your help, I appreciate it very much!